# error string(161) " Cannot POST /api/2/trading/balance " HitBTC Api PHP

Tags: php, json, api

My code is below doesn't work, I basically want to display the account balance, I am using `var_dum($curl_response)` to actually see where the code stopped, cuz if I dump the final result I get null.

```
<?php
 $headers = array ( "Content-Type: application/json" );
 $service_url = 'https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/trading/balance';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxxx:xxx"); //Your credentials goes here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //IMP if the url has https and you don't want to verify source certificate

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($curl_response);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($curl_response);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for those who came here looking for an answer I fixed it myself and this is to help you out, this is what really works with HitBTC without the need to their SDK.

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/trading/balance'); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'xxxx:xxxxx'); // API AND KEY
$return = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch); print_r($return); ?>
```